# Can't install the debian9 package inside the Docker image

Tags: debian-stretch

I've run Debian 9 in as the Docker image. Next I've tried to install the `vim` package, but it's got error

```
apt update && apt install -y vim && apt install -y ps
...
Err:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]
Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
  404  Not Found
Err:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
```

After that I googled an info and changed the `/etc/atp/sources.list` file to

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stable-security/updates main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
```

and apt can execute the command `update` without issues. But I still couldn't install any package.

I found the address for archive distrs (https://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/dists/stretch/). Obviously I ought to use the `deb https://archive.debian.org/debian-archive` repos, but can't fetch how to specify them properly.

The image `debian:12` works fine. Should I copy the repos from it?

Comment: No, you should not mix different OS versions, this only creates further problems. Debian 9 is EOL. There are archive mirrors you can use, but you should upgrade your applications to work with more modern versions.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, so I can't run Debian 9 in my work totally? Without repos it's useless.

Comment: Of course you can, by using the archive repos. But it's highly discouraged because it's insecure. It's also off topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the repo URL for the archive one, using something like :

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib
```